# How do I move my mySQL database from my local server to Heroku?

Tags: php, mysql, heroku, phpmyadmin

I created a mySQL database with phpMyAdmin. In this database I stored the names and the location of my friends (along with an id as a primary key for the database). I wrote and run the following php script to retrieve these data from the database and project them on my local web server (XAMPP):

```
<?php

$dbServername = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = 'Friends';

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM friends;';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);


if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['id'], ' ', $row['name'], ' ', $row['location']. '<br>';

    }
}

?>
```

Now I want to access this database from my other computer where I need them to make some cool data visualisations at the front-end.

One way is to build again phpMyAdmin (and XAMPP) at the other computer and add a new user to this database.

The other way, which I chose, is to move my mySQL database from my local server to Heroku.

How can this easily be done step-by-step (by using ClearDB?)?

Can I sync my local server to Heroku so that when I make changes to the database at the local server then Heroku is automatically updated?

Comment: phpMyAdmin isn't a database, it's a tool for viewing your *MySQL* database.

Comment: You are comparing a hoster to a database administration tool. How do you expect to get something like this answered. What is the problem? Creating a dump of that database? Or Importing it over at Heroku? Or accesing the Heroku-server? …

Comment: Ok, I edited my post and I think that now it makes more sense (?). Yes, now Google search is easier @ceejayoz (even though I have already found some of these links).

Comment: Just to be very clear, I would like a short answer to my second question guys if you do not mind. Can I sync in a way my local server to Heroku or I must update every time the database from the local server to Heroku manually?

Comment: You'd first need to clarify what "Heroku" means. They don't offer MySQL except via third-party services. Their main database offering is *PostgreSQL*. *Some* of their MySQL vendors may let you set up replication, but I'd say you're better off handling data migration as part of your deployment process.

Comment: I think that you can use clearDB (https://elements.heroku.com/addons/cleardb) on Heroku for mySQL if I am right (but perhaps you know better). However, keep in mind that I am not in any way committed to mySQL but I simply created pretty easily a mySQL database with XAMPP (and phpMyAdmin) so this why  I mentioned it.

Comment: You can, but that's a third-party add-on. There are several. If you're going to use ClearDB's MySQL solution, that's important for the question, because different providers may have different rules on replication.

Comment: I agree with you @ceejayoz but remember that my question is "How can this easily be done step-by-step?". So I expected someone to tell me how to do this in detail (with including possibly a third-party like clearDB or whatever she/he finds necessary for performing this task).

Comment: That's not how this works. We're not a tutorial authoring service - we answer specific questions where *you* provide that sort of detail.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @ceejayoz. However, I was not myself if sure I had to use clearDB so why even to mention it. In any case, I edited my post regarding this. However, my main question is essentially still  answered (by you).

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple option depending on how much access you have on the database server etc.

Guessing you want to still use mysql on heroku you could easyliy do the following:

- Use phpmyadmin to export all databases/tables that you want and reimport them into your heroku database. Im not familiar with heroku but im guessing that they offer some kind of web database management.
- You could use a one time/permanent mysql replication from the one server to the other. There are multiple options on to how to set this up (master <-> master, master -> slave, etc.). Here is a quick tutorial on how to set  up a master -> slave replication: http://www.clusterdb.com/mysql-cluster/get-mysql-replication-up-and-running-in-5-minutes

There are more options but this are the ones that came to mind.

Comment: Thank you for your response(upvote). Yes, I had clearly the first option in my mind. However, I was thinking if I can sync in way my local server to Heroku so that every time I change something at the local server then Heroku is automatically updated. Is this possible or I must do it every time manually (or I must do it directly on the Heroku database)?

Comment: The second option could do this but it can only be done if you have the right server permissions to create mysql replications. You need to look if you have the necessary rights on your server and if heroku supports it!

Comment: Ok, got it. So essentially I will manually move my SQL database from the local server of my one computer to Heroku and then I will access it from my other computer (which has my javascript front-end stuff) by having a webhook or API call to Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use a tool made for migrating the database. This would allow you to distribute your database and the contents if necessary to multiple instances without replicating data that is not needed. For instance if you have test data in your local database that you do not want replicated but you do want the table changes to be replicated this would be a much better solution. This is a better solution if you are planning on distributing your application in the future.

I think one of the more common solutions is Phinx here is a link to their page. https://phinx.org/

Edit:

What exactly does this give you? It would make you create a migration file for all of the changes you make to the database for instance if you add a table or change a column name/size/type etc you would add a new migration file. The file can have change or up and down methods this would be used to migrate your database to the new version or rollback. You can have inserts and other stuff so you could use this if you wanted to move data. What you would do is make your migration files. Then copy these to the server and run migrate. It would change the database schema and data to match what yours had. Is it automatic? No but what it does give you is the ability to migrate from one heroku instance to another without needing to setup replication again etc. You would setup the database name and then re-run your migrations and it would insert/create your database. Basically the only downside is the changes do not instantly change your heroku instance you would need to upload your file changes and migrations and run migrate.

Here is a good overview on phinx https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/phinx.html

Benefits of doing it this way:

- Database can be setup anywhere with just running a script.
- Database can is can be versioned so you can roll forward or back to new or old versions
- Not tied to a database on a particular instance/need
- No need for all the setup or maintenance of a replicated server.

Comment: Thank you for your response(upvote). This is a pretty interesting answer. However, it is not entirely clear to me (perhaps you can edit a bit). Specifically, what it the benefit of using a tool like this? Is it something related to my second question ("Can I sync my local server to Heroku so that when I make changes to the database at the local server then Heroku is automatically updated?") if I understand right?

Comment: Ill update the answer. I don't think it solves the problem in the way you are thinking about it just gives you a different solution to the problem possibly. Ill update and if its still unclear leave another comment.